# Odoo 10 amount_residual field in account_move_line

Tags: odoo

I would like to understand what represents amount_residual column in account_move_line table.

Odoo 10.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the amount pending payment of the invoice. 
Let me know if it was helpful.